# Parse and Populating TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

I have been trying to do this for a few days and Im stuck.  I am using parse as my backend.  I don't want to use parse's own ParseTableView to setup my View.   I want to understand what is going on with this basic app before I start a more difficult app.  How do I use the data from parse to populate my Table??? Thank you.

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  BraveRetiredNumbers
//

#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *playerTableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *testArrary;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *parseClassName;
@end

@implementation ViewController


@synthesize testArrary;
@synthesize playerArray;
@synthesize playerTableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveFromParse)];
    self.testArrary = @[@"Apple",@"Banana",@"Peach",@"Grape",@"Strawberry",@"Watermelon"];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.playerArray count];
    //return [testArrary count];
}

- (void) retrieveFromParse {

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Player"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@\n",objects);
        if (!error) {
            playerArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];

        }
    }];

    [playerTableView reloadData];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [playerTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *SimpleIdentifier = @"playerCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [playerTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleIdentifier];
    }


    //PFObject *tempObject = [playerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //NSDictionary *tempDic = [playerArray objectAtIndex:@"playerName"];

    cell.textLabel.text = [tempDic objectForKey:@"playerName"];

    //cell.textLabel.text = [testArrary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}


@end
```

Comment: I think the best way to achieve what you want, is to make async request to parse, get result and show them in your TableView as usually.
But I don't see any reason to do that.

Comment: So how would you go about doing that through the code?

Comment: Check Parse.com documentation. Here are code to make async request:
https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS
After request completes store values in your App, and show it as usually you do.